# Quick calculus question

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

IS it true that we can write the closed open interval $[a,b)$ as follows?
$$[a,b) = \bigcap_{n} \left(a - \frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n} \right] $$ 
thanks

Comment: No, $a$ is not contained in the union, you get $(a,b)$ that way.

Comment: Note : $[a,b)$ is neither closed or open. I think you meant "half-closed half-open" to mention the end points.

Comment: yeah i meant that lol

Comment: should it be $a - \frac{1}{n}$ right?

Comment: No, now there are elements $<a$ in the union. @Citizen

Comment: Still doesn't work with intersection. Assuming $n=1$ is the initial point. Then $b-1$ is the maximum element of the intersection since ever element must be in $(a-1,b-1]$.

Comment: You really shouldn't keep editing your question. A lot of people have tried to answer your question, and every time you change it, you invalidate their answer. Instead, add to your question, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the revised question. The answer is no, $[a,b)$ is not the **union** of the intervals $(a-\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]$. For the union contains points $x\lt a$.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: There is now trouble near $b$. We have an intersection. So for example if $a=1$ and $b=10$, the entire chunk from $9$ to $10$ is missing. Since your question is evolving, I will not change the answer until things stabilize.

Comment: How can we write then $[a,b)$ as a union or intersection of intervals of the form $( \times, \times ]$

Comment: You can use $\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty [a,b-\frac{1}{n})$, where the starting point $k$ is chosen so that these really are intervals (that's only an issue if $|b-a|$ is small. Or else you can use an intersection of intervals $(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $a$ is not in any $(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$.